# How to get Localdate as parameter?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form which looks like this:

```
<form th:action="@{/viewExpenses}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date" class="control-label col-md-3">Date:-</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" th:name="date"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now when I submit this form I wish to get the date value as `LocalDate`. So on my controller I did:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewExpenses", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String expenseDetails(Model model, @RequestParam("date")
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate date) {

    BigDecimal totalExpense = new BigDecimal(0);

    List<Expenditure> e = expenditureService.viewExpenseDetails(date);

    for (Expenditure exp : e) {
        totalExpense = totalExpense.add(exp.getAmount());
    }

    model.addAttribute("showExpenditure", true);
    model.addAttribute("totalExpense", totalExpense);
    model.addAttribute("expenses", e);
    return "finance/expensedetails";
}
```

For now I get date value in my controller as `null`. I have tried changing pattern of `@DateTimeFormat` but it is still not working.
what might be the correct way to receive date parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the binding here is not happening.you can try using spring:form tag and bind the controller object via modelAttribute.